# How to add css3 to your project mvc web application visual studio 2015

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, css-selectors

**Problem**

**cannot add navigation menu to my project because css3 not need to
define why ?**

it display with green lines in all css file why

**How to solve this problem ?**

**my code**

```
<head>

    <link href="~/Content/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
 <div class="grid">
        <div class="grid__item">
            <nav class="header">

                <a href="#" class="menu-icon1">&#9776; menu</a>

                <ul>

                    <li><a href="#" class="current">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

                </ul>

            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I create menu.css file in content folder i add following code :
**css3**

```
@import "compass/css3";

$base-font-size:    16px!default;
$base-line-height:  24px!default;
$base-spacing-unit: $base-line-height!default;

body {
    background: grey;
    color: #555;
}

.header {

    width: 100%;
    background-color: #4C8FEC;
    height: $base-line-height * 2;
    margin-top: $base-line-height;
}
a {

    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    &:hover {
    color: white;

}

}

.current {

    color: white;

}

.menu-icon1 {

    display:inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: $base-line-height * 2;
    color: black;
    line-height: $base-line-height * 2;
    text-align: center;;

    }


    nav ul, nav:active ul {

        display: none;
        position: relative;
        padding: 0 $base-spacing-unit;
        background: #4C8FEC;
        width: 100%;
        list-style: none;

    }

    nav li {

        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px 0;
        margin: 0;

    }

    nav:hover ul {

        display: block;
    }


/*MEDIA QUERY*/

// @include media-query(desk){


@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {

nav {

    float: left;


    .menu-icon1 {
        display: none;
    }   
}

nav ul, nav:active ul {

        display: inline;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;

    }

    nav li {

        display: inline-block;
        width: auto;
        padding: 0 $base-spacing-unit;
        line-height: $base-line-height * 2;

    }


}
```

image to my problem
[image: css3 not defined to work in visual studio 2015]

Comment: you have a normal css file. you want to use compass with sass i think. you need a compiler for this.

Comment: That is php + css. You are trying to invent a new language concept. I guess. Remove dollar sign and use actual parameters.

Comment: ok what i do to compile that

Comment: install compass on your system and let compass watch your scss file. compass will then create css files.

Comment: [this tutorial](http://www.zingdesign.com/the-sass-and-compass-tutorial-for-absolute-beginners/) may help you.

Comment: how to install compass

Comment: have a look at the tutorial.

Comment: i will see it . but this meaning if i need to add css3 i must make these steps

Comment: it has nothing to do with css3.

Comment: thank you it solved